# Using LightFM for Retail Customer Recommendation based on purchased products quantities

Tags: lightfm

I am looking at using LightFM for recommending products to customers in retail stores based on the products the customer has bought in past. In the customer buying history, I have data regarding the products along with the purchase quantities for each product the customer has bought. The customer might have bought products with quantities ranging from 1 to 100 or more.
I am looking for suggestions on how I can convert these product-wise purchased quantities to the rating score of 1 to 5.

Considering the customer purchase quantity range, I am considering if a customer bought just 1 qty, then to keep the rating as 3, 2-3 qty then rating as 4 and more than 3 quantities, then to consider the rating as 5.

Looking for your suggestion.
Thank you.